# Remove a filter added by a plugin

Tags: php, filters

I'm using a plugin that adds this filter :

```
$this->base    = 'hotel-room';
$this->taxBase = 'hotel-room-category';
add_filter( 'single_template', array( $this, 'registerSingleTemplate' ) );
```

I want to remove this filter because I want to be able to manage this file in my child-theme.

The filter is part of this class :

```
class HotelRoomRegister implements Lib\PostTypeInterface {
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $base;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $taxBase;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->base    = 'hotel-room';
        $this->taxBase = 'hotel-room-category';

        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'removeLocationTagMetaBox' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'removeExtraServicesTagMetaBox' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'removeReviewTagMetaBox' ) );

        add_filter( 'single_template', array( $this, 'registerSingleTemplate' ) );
    }
```

I added the following to my functions.php in my child theme, but it doesn't change anything:

```
global $HotelRoomRegister;
remove_filter( 'single_template', array( 'hotel-room', 'registerSingleTemplate' ) );
```

How can I manage this ?

Also, in case it's helpful, here is the function linked to this filter in the same class:

```
public function registerSingleTemplate( $single ) {
    global $post;

    if ( isset( $post ) && $post->post_type == $this->base ) {

        if ( ! file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/single-' . $this->base . '.php' ) ) {
            return MIKADO_HOTEL_CPT_PATH . '/hotel-room/templates/single-' . $this->base . '.php';
        }
    }

    return $single;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some digging managed to find the asnwer and instead of removing the filter you can overrid the single_template filter to add your own custom template.

```
add_filter( 'single_template', 'my_custom_single_template', 99, 1 );

function my_custom_single_template( $single ) {

    global $post;

    if ( isset( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'hotel-room' ) {
        $single = require_once( STYLESHEETPATH . '/single-hotel-room.php');
    }

    return $single;
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your fast reply. I have done this change, but it doesn't work. Still the same result.

Comment: Question, why is the class at this place, and in "add_filter" is something else ?

Comment: In the add filter the array takes the $this because the function defined is hooked inside the class itself and in your case you want to remove the filter outside the class. So if you were going to put the remove_filter inside the 'HotelRoomRegister' class then you would use $this

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip. So i wonder why the remove_filter does'nt take effect. If i comment the add_filter in the original file, it works well. I readed that maybe i remove filter before it has been added ? How can i manage this ?

Comment: I updated the answer. Try to add 99 after the array which is the priority. If this does not work either ther is another way

Comment: done, not working :( ! have you seen my last comment about removing before the filter is being added ?

Comment: Ok another approach is to create a function and hook it at the 'init' action.
So you can have something like: add_action( 'init', 'remove_filters' );
function remove_filters(){ remove_filter( 'single_template', array( 'HotelRoomRegister', 'registerSingleTemplate' ), 99 ); }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101324/discussion-between-gregory-and-giannisrig).